# checkbox change using jquery/javascript not working inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to select/unselect all checkbox by checking one master checkbox inside my bootstrap modal, but javascript/jquery script not working with input type checkbox.

here is my html code-

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
```

here is jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkAll").change(function () { alert('here');
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

when i check on checkbox it doesn't show alert.

why this not working in bootstrap modal?

I've tried to show alert inside input tag like this-

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="alert('hello');"/>
```

which also not works!

Comment: You can refer following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/h3WDq/1031/);

Comment: hello Rajesh, this fiddle doesn't works for me.

Comment: Have you tried `on`? If this is not working try using a delegate: `$(document).on("change", "#checkAll", function(){ alert("Hello") })`

Comment: i found the solution myself after two days head bang, i just remove the parent div of input field and it works perfectly! the parent div class contains some unexpected styling from a css file named green.css.

Comment: thanks all of you guys!

Answer (score 2):

This might be cause by not using `.on`.

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/20tp1zac/) that will explain your situation.

Comment: this js fiddle works perfectly outside the modal, doesn't works inside.

Comment: Okay, please recreate your problem in a JSFiddle so that i can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way  used to **[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkAll").on('change', function () { alert('here');
        var inputCheck =$(this);
        console.log("Checked -"+inputCheck .is(":checked"));
    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your icheck.js   that comes with the bootstrap template.

check this out
http://seegatesite.com/checked-checkbox-adminlte-bootstrap-in-jquery/

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$('#radiobt1').on('ifChecked', function(event){
 alert('New value');
});   
 });
```